# Making a 'count' in a query to find out how many of the same variables are in a column

Tags: ms-access, count

I am trying to set up a Query, I have a table called 'Cards' with each specific ID only having one owner, while each owner has at least 1 card.

I am trying to set up a count to tell me how many cards each person has and then after that, only show which person has AT LEAST 6 amount of cards.

Things I've tried:

Under Card #, in criteria, I tried doing a count(*) > 6 but it keeps returning a generic error, I tried a count(sum) for each person and finally a sum(>6) under the 'last name' and nothing works I've been working on this for a while and I'm genuinely stuck.

I am using Microsoft Access 2013 and it has to be done within the query and 'build'

Answer (score 1):

Create a query in Query by Example view. Show table `Cards`. Now, in the Design menu, toggle on Totals. Add Owner as a Group By field. Add Card # (you should really change that to something without spaces and special characters) and change it's Total field to Count. Run the query and you'll see the first set of results -- Count of cards for each owner. Next, go back in design and add simply `>6` to the criteria of the Count of Cards column. This will show the second listing that you describe.

Comment: Thank you, but for some reason it only shows "1" for each and shows them each multiple times. I have a First name, Last name, Phone number for each as well and need them all to be displayed in the same table. I am not sure exactly what example view is.

Comment: Query by Example is the default design view for Access, instead of SQL view. It sounds like your current query includes a Group By level like Card# or CardName, that is unique to each card (hence count of 1 per card#). You need to drop this if you want to count total cards per owner. Card# must only be in a Count column, not a Group By column.